# Outlook shows bigger text when window display is set to Medium

Tags: email, outlook, newsletter

I'm having an issue with Outlook and when Windows Display (Control Panel > All Control Panel Items > Display) is set to Medium - 125% (or larger)

The text in the newsletter appears bigger and is creating issues with spacing. Although most of the issues with this can be resolved, I would like to know if there is a way to force Outlook to respect the pixel sizing as defined in the html email.

An example code block is something on these lines

```
    ...
    <td width="460" valign="baseline">
            <p style="font-size:16px;margin-top:0;margin-bottom:0;margin-left:0;margin-right:0;" >Hello </p>
    </td>
    ...
```

The text inside the `<p>` tag is 16px on a machine that has Windows Display 100% but is larger when Windows Display 125% (interestingly, the browser still respects the 16px and does not increase the font size like Outlook)

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you're taking the right approach to this problem. Please look at it another way.

The user said "I want my text to be bigger". They probably said that because they have a very high res display or they have visual difficulties. It's their preference, if not their need, to have bigger text.

You're saying "how do I override the user's preference for my cosmetic convenience?".

Don't do that. Fix your layout's design so it adapts better to varying text sizes.

Reduce your image use and/or place your images so that they can handle being pushed around by the text. Consdier using scalable units like `em` or percentage font sizes to be more friendly toward people with visual difficulties or very-high-res displays.

### Background:

The reason Windows scales fonts (and pixels) like this is because software developers for the platform have been consistently ignoring the font sizes the user sets in Explorer and the theme. Apps often force the use of their own fonts with specific pixel sizing instead of using the system fonts and sizes.

This has led to lots of apps that're unusable for people with visual difficulties, on media PCs, etc.

Microsoft wanted to give users a way to override these badly behaved programs, so they gave users a way to scale the pixel sizes provided by applications by a fixed percentage. Essentially they redefined a font "px" as an abstract unit that can be scaled.

Your HTML email is trying to be one of those badly behaved programs.

Comment: @HamishRouse Guess you're stuck with `px` then. Fair enough. You can't, and shouldn't, prevent the user from changing font sizes though. If you want perfect display send a PDF or an image with a text alternative.

Comment: Interesting answer however email clients don't use the same baseline across the board - http://www.campaignmonitor.com/blog/post/3447/should-i-use-em-or-px-when-coding-for-html-email/ Totally agree with adjusting the layout where possible to cater increased font sizes however sometimes this not always possible with image heavy/pixel perfect newsletters/email. In a perfect world, email clients and browsers would work the same - zoom by default not just increase font size.

Comment: Alternatively a link to an online web version of the newsletter if the layout becomes to horrible to look at in an email client ;)

Comment: Yeah, web browsers now zoom rather than increasing font sizes because so many designers tried to create "pixel perfect" layouts and ignored font sizes. Mail clients may eventually do the same, but IMO the real problem is the designers prioritizing pixel-perfect layouts over usability and accessibility. Alas, the client often doesn't agree.